# Происхождение слова "волоокий"

Tags: этимология

О людях с красивыми глазами иногда говорят "волоокие". А что это означает? Неужели, глаза сравниваются с глазами волов?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ВОЛООКИЙ волоокая, волоокое (перевод греч. boopis, букв. с глазами, как у вола) (поэт. устар.). Имеющий большие выразительные глаза.

Словарь Ушакова.

"И синий вол, исполненный очей",- Б. Г. Глаза у этих животных и правда выразительные, но боюсь, ныне такой комплимент могут понять неправильно.

[image]

*"Волоокая красавица"*

Comment: Зря боитесь - поймут. Делайте комплименты, не стесняйтесь!

Comment: По-моему, в понятие "волоокий" входит не только "с большими глазами", но взгляд должен быть спокойный и с поволокой - этот взгляд придаёт красоту,а не огромные глаза. Есть люди с огромными светлыми глазами навыкате - их никто волоокими не называет.Волоокие - большие миндалевидные карие(как у вола),спокойные, выразительные, как бы подёрнутые дымкой.

Comment: @Людмила, у Ушакова и написано, что глаза должны быть *большими и выразительными*. По поводу обязательности карих глаз и непременной спокойности, не соглашусь. Вот пример энергичной волоокости.

>Там жила ее подруга, Наталья Ильинична Опричина, девица волоокая, полногрудая, **энергичная**, славный человек и отличный товарищ. [Ф. К. Сологуб. Путь в Дамаск (1910)]

Нацкорпус.

А вот голубоглазой.


![alt text][1]

Фото [отсюда](http://club.foto.ru/gallery/photos/2118709/?&author_id=474799&sort=date&next_photo_id=2118714&prev_photo_id=2108943).

  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/WmsQgDs.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Да, у них очень большие, выразительные глаза, с длинными пушистыми ресницами. "Глаза как у коровы" - то же самое.

Comment: Красавцы 
![Похищение Европы](http://100sovietpainters.ru/Fantasy/fantasy-14.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Людмила согласен один раз видел т.н. с поволокою глаза. Редкость или редкое состояние у человека.

Answer (score 0):

Но преимущественно все-таки это слово относится к карим глазам. Ведь это постоянный эпитет богини Геры (как "совоокая", то есть, с совиными глазами - эпитет Афины), а ее священным животным была именно корова, сама же она, если не ошибаюсь, была темноволоса и темноглаза (ну, по крайней мере, по представлениям древних греков).